# When radio is changed updated select of same value

Tags: javascript

I have a radio input and a select with both have the same values. When the radio is selected I was to update the select so that the select has the same active option and the same when I change the select I want the radio to change.

```js
$(".change").change(function() {
 var selected = $(this).val();
 $(".change").val(selected);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="yes" value="yes" checked  class="change"/>
<label for="yes">Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="no" value="no" class="change" />
<label for="yes">No</label>

<select name="application_type" class="change">
 <option value="yes" selected>Yes</option>
 <option value="no">No</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the snippet, this might help you for now :D

```js
 var selected;
jQuery(".change").on('change', function() {
  if(this.type == 'radio') {
   selected = jQuery(this).attr('id');

    jQuery(".change[name=application_type]").val(selected);
  }else{
    
    selected = jQuery(this).val();
    jQuery('.change[type=radio][value='+selected+']').prop('checked', true);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="yes" value="yes" checked  class="change"/>
<label for="yes">Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="no" value="no" class="change" />
<label for="yes">No</label>

<select name="application_type" class="change">
 <option value="yes">Yes</option>
 <option value="no">No</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks but this only works if you change the radio button. When you change the select is doesn't update the radio.

Comment: updating, hold on

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(".change").on("change",function(){
  console.log($(this).val(),$(this).attr("type"));
  if($(this).attr("type")=="radio"){
    $("select.change").val($(this).val());
  }if(typeof $(this).attr("type")=="undefined"){
    $("#"+$(this).val()).prop("checked","checked");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="yes" value="yes" checked  class="change"/>
<label for="yes">Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="no" value="no" class="change" />
<label for="yes">No</label>

<select name="application_type" class="change">
 <option value="yes" selected>Yes</option>
 <option value="no">No</option>
</select>
```

You were doing it wrong as mentioned above is a correct solution. Because you were changing the value of radio was not working.